# Ajax returning JSON implementing it?

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

I have a codeigniter application, and I am making some changes to it.

The first change I am doing is to allow admin users to place orders through the admin panel, where they have receieved orders through magazines, exhibitions etc.

So I have linked a form up an ajax request the pulls the item info back from the database and then encodes it into JSON and then returns it to my view.

What I am having trouble with is display this to the user in nice format.

Ideally I want to show,

```
date.name  
data.price
data.description
```

I need to show them these details with a form as they are going to enter a quantity into a form field but I need to generate this information and HTML on the fly, is this possible? Or would I be best building a view and then returning that via ajax?

My current ajax request,

```
            $.ajax({
            url     : '<?php echo current_url(); ?>',
            data    : "txtKeywords="+$("#txtKeywords").val()+"&search=Search For Item",
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success : function(data)
            {
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Add the view to your page like this:

```
<script id="view" type="text/html">
    <div>
        <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
        <p>Price: {{price}}</p>
        <p>Description: {{description}}</p>
    </div>
<script>
```

Add mustache and the mustache jquery plugin to your page: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Now in the success callback you do

```
function(data) {
    var template = $("#view").html();
    var view = $.mustache( template, data );
    $("body").append( view );
}
```

That's it. Mustache renders the view with the data returned by the json call and then the code appends it to the body.